# Interest in Photo of the Week?

Tags: discussion

We used to have [Topic of the Week](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/169/31410) a few years ago but it lost steam after a few weeks. I've seen other sites have Photo/Screenshot/etc. of the Week and would like to introduce it to Astronomy. Any thoughts regarding this?

**NB:** Also, see [Should we revive the Topic of the Week?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/31410) and [Monthly focus tag](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/465/31410)

Comment: I like the idea *in principle*, but... Are you thinking of restricting to users submitting their own personal astro-photos, or can they be any astronomical image from any source? You also might add to your question how the process works. For example Photography SE showcases photos, there must be a meta post that explains the mechanism; who decides what photo gets posted, who is responsible for deciding which one, etc. Note that *proposals that make more work for moderators* usually don't get very far! :-)

Comment: I think photo of the week would be more appropriate for chat than meta.