# Monthly focus tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There seems to be an interest in reviving the topic of the week in some form:

[Should we revive the Topic of the Week?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/6)

My proposal is based on the top upvoted "topic of the month" idea there.

---

Each month we could highlight a tag on meta with a title like this:

> #### This Month's Focus Tag: [the-moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon)

The focus tag would be the centerpiece for several efforts. We could:

- feature clear questions under the tag with one or more excellent answers
- encourage asking follow-up questions
- engage in editing of posts under the tag
- take the opportunity to make sure the tag description is appropriate and update the tag wiki
- make [blog posts](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/460/6) related to the topic, if the blog idea catches on

The answer space of the meta post would be used to coordinate efforts like assembling lists of posts in need of editing or brainstorming ideas to add to the tag wiki or blog. If desired, it could even be used for sandboxing questions related to the focus tag to have the community review before posting in main to prevent poor reception.

What do you think of this idea?

Comment: Chat discussion, for anyone interested: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47808186#47808186

Comment: First focus tag post: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/467/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this idea seems popular, I have some suggestions for the first focus tag:

- [tidal-forces](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-forces)
- [photometry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photometry)
- [meteorite](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorite)
- [dust](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust)

These are all high use tags without descriptions that seemed potentially eye-catching to me. I also have some suggestions for highlighted questions:

[tidal-forces](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-forces):

[How did Mars come to have a 24 hour 39 minute day?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12269/6)

[photometry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photometry):

[What is the ugriz magnitude system?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18986/6)

[meteorite](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorite):

[How do scientists know that a rock found on Earth came from Mars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2372/6)

[dust](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust):

[What is the difference between gas and dust in astronomy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/3663/6)

Please comment with the focus tag you want to see first, and feel free to give your thoughts on the highlighted questions and/or offer alternatives.

If you have other ideas for the focus tag, let us know in another answer.

Comment: My personal preference for this would be [tag:dust], which I think has seen a lot of good questions and answers miss out on attention, but these all seem reasonable choices.

Comment: They are all great! I also like dust because it has importance in many different subfields and most people will already have some familiarity with it or at least some ideas, so it's good to attract interest.