# This month's focus tag: dust

Tags: discussion, focus-tag

Welcome to our new series of monthly focus tags! This month's focus tag is [dust](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust).

**Featured Question:** [What is the difference between gas and dust in astronomy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/3663/6)

This question is great to start off with because it covers the definition of dust in astronomy, so if you're not sure what this tag is all about you should check it out!

The monthly focus tag is an opportunity for us to learn more about a topic and improve the site by taking a look at a particular area. Please take this opportunity to look at the questions and answers in [dust](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust). If you see anything that could be improved, take the opportunity to edit. If you have follow-up questions, go ahead and ask them (with the appropriate tag, of course). If you happen to know the answer to an unanswered question, we'd appreciate your input!

Also, this is a good chance to take a look at the tag excerpt and wiki. If it is empty or could be improved, perhaps you could help us out?

Feel free to use the answer space below to make community wiki lists of posts in need of editing, or to brainstorm ideas of what to add to the tag excerpt and wiki. Not sure about a particular [dust](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust) question you have? Go ahead and share your concerns below, so we can help guide you to framing the question on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Definition of [dust](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust) resulted in the need for the tag [dust-storm](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust-storm). Check it out and feel free to revise it as well. If you see any questions which need this tag or other questions under [dust](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust) that don't fit the new definition, you can discuss here.