# This month's focus tag: tidal-forces

Tags: discussion, focus-tag

Happy New Year! Last month we took a close look at the topic of [dust](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/467/6). This month's focus tag is [tidal-forces](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-forces).

**Featured Question:** [How did Mars come to have a 24 hour 39 minute day?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12269/6)

This question covers the impact of tidal forces on the rotation of planets, giving us a good look at the topic at hand.

The monthly focus tag is an opportunity for us to learn more about a topic and improve the site by taking a look at a particular area. Please take this opportunity to look at the questions and answers in [tidal-forces](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-forces). If you see anything that could be improved, take the opportunity to edit. If you have follow-up questions, go ahead and ask them (with the appropriate tag, of course). If you happen to know the answer to an unanswered question, we'd appreciate your input!

Also, this is a good chance to take a look at the tag excerpt and wiki. If it is empty or could be improved, perhaps you could help us out?

Feel free to use the answer space below to make community wiki lists of posts in need of editing, or to brainstorm ideas of what to add to the tag excerpt and wiki. Not sure about a particular [tidal-forces](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-forces) question you have? Go ahead and share your concerns below, so we can help guide you to framing the question on the site.

Comment: [In planetary science, what exactly is, or is not, a tidal force?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29148/7982)

Comment: New focus tag coming soon. Just wanted everyone to know we haven't forgotten!