# This month's focus tag: white-dwarf

Tags: discussion, focus-tag

Sorry for the delay in the focus tag this month! Last month we took a close look at the topic of [tidal forces](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/480/6). This month's focus tag is [white-dwarf](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white-dwarf).

**Featured Question:** [Is there a possibility that a white dwarf can turn into a neutron star or a black hole?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25900/6)

The nature of white dwarfs is covered in some detail in order to answer the title question.

This month we also have a blog post related to the topic: [Can merging white dwarfs form variable stars?](https://aneyeontheuniverse.wordpress.com/2019/02/18/can-merging-white-dwarfs-form-variable-stars/)

The monthly focus tag is an opportunity for us to learn more about a topic and improve the site by taking a look at a particular area. Please take this opportunity to look at the questions and answers in [white-dwarf](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white-dwarf). If you see anything that could be improved, take the opportunity to edit. If you have follow-up questions, go ahead and ask them (with the appropriate tag, of course). If you happen to know the answer to an unanswered question, we'd appreciate your input!

Also, this is a good chance to take a look at the tag excerpt and wiki. If it is empty or could be improved, perhaps you could help us out? Don't forget to follow the guidelines for writing good [tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337/274942).

Feel free to use the answer space below to make community wiki lists of posts in need of editing, or to brainstorm ideas of what to add to the tag excerpt and wiki. Not sure about a particular [white-dwarf](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white-dwarf) question you have? Go ahead and share your concerns below, so we can help guide you to framing the question on the site.

Comment: Sorry, where is the "wiki"?

Comment: @Max0815 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tags/white-dwarf/info

Comment: thanks! That clears some confusion!

Comment: @Max0815 Unfortunately, I had to rollback your wiki edits. We sent you a message about it. I've updated this post with a link to additional guidance to help future users avoid the same mistake. Thanks for your interest in improving the site!

Comment: I read thru the criteria. So isn't it viable to put the general definition from Wikipedia though?

Comment: No, that would be plagiarism.

Comment: Oh, ok. I see. Let me try again.

Comment: I added a non-Wikipedia definition purely based on my prior knowledge. Not as good wording and grammar but hey its original.

Comment: ♦  I have a suggestion. Put the month name on there so it won't be too confusing on which month it is

Comment: @Max0815 That's a good idea. For now, we're still getting in the rhythm.

Comment: Ah, ok. Anyways good to know you like my suggestion :P