# Reviving the Astronomy SE blog

Tags: discussion, blog

Our blog, [An Eye On the Universe](https://aneyeontheuniverse.wordpress.com/), has been inactive for two years. I recently joined the short list of contributors (see these posts: [1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57635216#57635216) and [2](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/do-you-want-to-write-for-our-blog)), and have begun to contribute to the blog.

So I am wondering, is it a good idea to revive our blog, even though it is rather old and lacks contribution? If anyone is interested or have any questions, please post this in an answer.

Comment: How many blogposts have been contributed in total?

Comment: @uhoh There is one post (bar the welcome post) and one draft.