# Blog Status Update #1

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog

You might have heard that we're trying to [rustle up support](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/2153) [for a site blog](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/460/2153). It seems like we have a critical mass of potential writers such that it should be able to support itself with content for the foreseeable future, even if people aren't able to write as often as they'd like. With that in mind, called2voyage and I have taken steps to set it all up, and we now have a site, [An Eye on the Universe](https://aneyeontheuniverse.wordpress.com/) (hat tip to called2voyage for the same), created using WordPress, a fairly accessible platform that has the features we need, like LaTeX support.

Here's where it stands:

- At the moment, we've edited [the default post WordPress publishes](https://aneyeontheuniverse.wordpress.com/2019/01/03/the-journey-begins/) so there's actually something for the casual visitor to see.
- There's [an About](https://aneyeontheuniverse.wordpress.com/about/) page with some super-helpful links.
- called2voyage and I are [administrators](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/customizing-wordpress/managing-users-on-your-wordpress-site/adding-users-to-your-wordpress-site/#administrator), which means we can do basically anything on the site.
- We already have one person added as a [contributor](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/customizing-wordpress/managing-users-on-your-wordpress-site/adding-users-to-your-wordpress-site/#contributor), meaning they can submit posts for publication but still need approval from an administrator or editor to publish.

. . . That's about it, but it was a reasonably productive day.

If you're thinking about writing for the blog, you'll need to create a WordPress account, then ask us to give you contributor access, either by commenting here or pinging one of us [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/815/the-observatory).

If you want to tell us in more detail what you'd be interested in writing about, write up an answer [here](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/2153).

As always, of course, if you have anything else you want to discuss - comments on the theme, say - feel free to write up an answer to this question.